# Controls in datatemplate not receiving input interaction

Tags: wpf, xaml, mef, datatemplate

I have a `DataTemplate` for a class as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:CalendarEvent}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Width="80"
                     Margin="0 0 20 0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       FontSize="36"
                       Text="{Binding EventName}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                <Run Text="From " /><Run Text="{Binding EventStartDate}" />
                <Run Text=" till " /><Run Text="{Binding EventEndDate}" /></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

After using the template as an `ItemTemplate` of an `ItemsControl`, I can't interact with the controls in it. When I try to click on any of the controls (since it is an item in a list), the whole `ItemsControl` is focused. In fact, I put the `TextBox` there to verfiy that the template is not receiving interactions. My original template has a `Button` (which was not receiving any `Click` event, either).

I should point out that the template is part of a plugin in a `MEF` application. Could that be the reason? In the host project, controls in a `DataTemplate` are working.

**EDIT**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:CalendarEvent}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       FontSize="36"
                       Text="{Binding EventName}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                <Run Text="From " /><Run Text="{Binding EventStartDate}" />
                <Run Text=" till " /><Run Text="{Binding EventEndDate}" /></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="80"
                     Margin="0 0 20 0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Moving the `TextBox` below the `TextBlock`s did it. It was obscured by them since they are automatically filling the width of the `Grid`.
I could also have set fixed widths for the `TextBlock`s.

Comment: Are you doing anything that could be setting IsEnabled=false? Use a WPF snoop application to look at the properties of those controls when they are running in your app. Use the one built into Visual Studio 2017, or a 3rd party one..eg. wpf snoop, or wpfinspector.

Comment: @ColinSmith Nothing is setting `IsEnabled` to `false`. I used the UI Debugging tools in VS 2015. BTW, Snoop and WPF Inspector cannot detect my application.

Comment: It was actually a no-issue. The problem, actually, was that the two `TextBlock`s have automatic widths that span across the `Grid` and since they appear after the `TextBox`, they effectively "cover" it. All I did was move the `TextBox` after them. Everything working once again!